# SharePoint Online - unused content report

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, site-usage, sharepoint-online-powershell

I would like to review the usage of my SPO site and extract a report with the following details:
Title, Created Date, Last Modified Date, Number of hits last 6 months, Last modified by, Created by

I need to identify areas that are unused to try to get them removed (details for each item on the site are required).

How can this be done? Some PowerShell script maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use graph api `GET /reports/getSharePointSiteUsageDetail(period='{period_value}')`

[sample](https://jerehuovinen.com/2019/02/12/getting-sharepoint-site-activity-from-graph-api-using-powershell/)

you can use native page in SharePoint Admin center, you check Actives sites and "Last Activity"
**https://m365x96529-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/AdminHome.aspx#/siteManagement**

Answer (score 0):

The other way is search with query like "**LastModifiedTimeForRetention<2021-01-01**". I am not saying that unused is the same as not updated, but this might help too.

You can use the query with GUI or with Graph API. Programmatically you can pull all the data you need for every "old" file. Here is [how to find old content in SharePoint](https://vladilen.com/office-365/how-to-find-old-content-on-your-onedrive-or-sharepoint-site/).